# Prevent controller action from direct execution by user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, explicit

I have a situation where i need to prevent users from explicitly calling say /town/addBuilding. Town is my controller and addBuilding is the action that is executed.

Now, the thing is that this action should only be executed in my program's code and not by a user requesting to execute it. Moreover, this action is executed like a callback. In my application_controller, when some condition is met, the controller action is triggered and there is a redirection. In php, a simple guard like defining a guard and checking against it would be enough. Is there an equivalent thing in rails and if so, what is the best way to implement it ?

Thanx for reading and i appreciate your help :)

EDIT: I'm pasting some code to make it clearer, note that /town/addBuilding was an example, the controller names and actions below are differently named.

Now, that is the actual application controller code, it is part of a browser game that i'm coding.

```
def checkQuest
if TavernQuest.hasQuest(current_user)
  quest = TavernQuest.getQuest(current_user)
  if quest.end_time < Time.now # get quest info and check if the quest has been completed
    TavernQuest.deleteQuest(current_user)
    redirect_to :controller => 'tavern', :action => 'monsterAttack'
  end
end
end
```

The tavern controller action is just the plain code that i want to execute, but only if the redirection happens inside the application controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to put logic into a controller which actually should belong in a model or a library.

Why do i say this: aside from the current_user and the redirect, all the code is more related to your model (where the knowledge should be) and not your controller. Your model knows when a user's quest is expired.

Example implementation:

```
class TavernQuest

  def self.user_quest_is_expired?(user)
    quest = getQuest(current_user)
    if quest && quest.end_time < Time.now 
      TavernQuest.deleteQuest(current_user)
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

and in your controller you just need to write

```
redirect_to :controller => 'tavern', :action => 'monsterAttack' if TavernQuest.user_quest_is_expired?(current_user)
```

Comment: That does not help much. How would you suggest doing that ? To me, it seems like controller code for sure.

Comment: Hello there, sorry for the late reply, i missed your edit. Your implementation is indeed clearer but it does not solve the explicit call problem. The user will still be able to execute tavern/monsterAttack. I want to prevent that and only call it on my redirection alone.

Comment: It seems that i can do that by including some more logic on the code, i will have to elaborate on that. Thanx ;)

Comment: What happens when you have no 'current_user' (anonymous user) at all with no quest but entirely wants to user to access by another controller.

Answer (score 0):

Put the addBuilding method under a line that starts with protected, as follows

```
protected
def addBuilding
   #your code
end
```

Enjoy!

**EDIT:** In addition to this you might also wanna use the before_filter in your controllers... I'll post the exact syntax soon.

```
 before_filter :addBuilding, :only => :method_name
```

method_name is the method from which :addBuilding can be accessed, no other method can access this method after adding in this line..

**EDIT:** Ok, so based on the info you provided, `protected` wont work since if we put your secret action under `protected` only the `tavern` controller will have access to it.

**EDIT:** Please consider using Sessions to check if the users have a valid session when they try to to execute the `monsterAttack` action..

Comment: Hello Jasdeep and thanx for the really quick reply. 
The problem is that i'm redirecting to addbuilding like "redirect_to :controller => 'town', :action => 'addbuilding through my application_controller (via a callback as i mentioned in the first post) and therefore private,protected do not work. The before_filter could work, but will a redirection inside the model work (through the method_name i mean, since i will have to call addbuilding eventually). I'll take a look, thanx :)

Comment: no problem Spyros, do take some time to Mark this answer as accepted in case it worked for you.. :)

Comment: why would you redirect from application_controller?? What makes you redirect to this action from application_controller? Also, before_filter should work just fine, just put the action that redirects after :only tag

Comment: I need to use the application_controller because this is a callback. It is based on time, so after 2 minutes it should be called before any other controller action. I will try before_filter now and let you know, thanx for the quick replies :)

Comment: Sure, please try the before_filter helper and see if it works.. Can you post your application_controller so that the community can have a look at it and analyse it?

Comment: hmm, i may be wrong but i think that before_filter would not work on this occasion, that is because before_filter should be a part of the town controller, while the redirection happens on the application controller. I will paste some code as you suggested, it will be better, i'm editing the main post now.

Comment: I have thought of using a session or some other lock situation (like a database value for instance), but i'm a bit afraid of race conditions and other possible caveats). However, if there is no other way, i guess i will have to do it this way, thanx :)

Comment: I would suggest you use Sessions instead of database locks, since sessions would be easier to implement..